# jQuery : Find prev element from current element

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to get a prev element from current element Like this.

```
<p class='target'>Target</p>

<ol>
  <li>start</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='start'>mid</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

For now, I'm in the **start** element.And I want to find the **target** element.

I try the below code to do this.

```
 $('.start').prev('.target');
```

But it didn't get the **target** DOM.

How can I do this?Any advice.

**Update ::**

My scenario is a bit complicated.

```
  <p>
  <ins>asdf</ins>
  </p>

<div>div (great-grandparent)
  <ul> 
     <li><del>(second ancestor - second grandparent)</del></li>   
     <ul>
       <li>
         <span>span</span>
       </li>
     </ul>
   </ul>   
</div>
```

Just assume I'm in the **span** and I try to find the "DEL and INS"
tags.What am I going to do?

And I try the below one.But it's not working.

```
$('span').closest('del');
$('span').closest('ins');
```

And the structure of the HTML is changing every time.That's why I'm afraid of.

Comment: `$('.start').closest('ol').prev('.target');` as `.target` is not immediate sibling thus you code didn't worked. You can traverse up to `ol` using `.closest()` then use `.prev()`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Thanks Federico, I think I got confused by the start text ;)

Comment: Your markup is invalid. Can't nest `<ul>` as child of `<ul>` or `<ol>`

Comment: That's only for reference.Don't worry about that.

Comment: What do you mean *"don't worry about that"*?  How are people to help when your code isn't even real or valid? See [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.start').closest('ol').prev('.target');
```

For traversing elements, it's important to understand their hierarchy. If you read the above code, you should be able to make out why it works.

It can be broken down like this:

- Select element with class `.start` => `<li class='start'>mid</li>`
- Get the closest (traverses up the tree) element of type `ol` in relation to `.start` => `<ol>`
- Get the previous element with class `.target` in relation to the previously selected `ol` element, which is the intended element => `<p class='target'>Target</p>`

Hope that helps.

Read about [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) from `jQuery` API.

Comment: What if I try to find closest ins,del and also span element.

Comment: @MariSelvan i suggest you rectify/format the updated html first. It's difficult to make out which is the node and which is the value/text.

Comment: Thank you.Now i'm making it fine(I thing).

Comment: @MariSelvan if you look at the sample html, there is no closing div, so it's still an invalid html. For element traversal, it's important to know the hierarchy well. Moreover, if your html keeps changing, your script will keep breaking.

Comment: Ok, I will close the div.But, my problem is that the HTML is still changing every time.That's why I need the help from Professionals like you.

Comment: @MariSelvan if html keeps changing, it won't be possible to write a common script. There should at least be some kind of a rule based on which the html is being created. If not, i don't think it would be possible to write a working script for all possible changes.

Comment: Ok, Then that's impossible to do with that.That's the problem the HTML is Changes every time and I can't predict this.

Answer (score 3):

```js
 console.log($(".start").closest( "ol" ).prev().html())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class='target'>Target</p>
<ol>
  <li>start</li>
  <ul>
    <li class='start'>mid</li>
  </ul>
</ol>
```